# Валидация номера телефона preg_match

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Привет всем!

 Как свалидировать номер телефона по формату +(999) 99 999 99 99 с помощью preg_match()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$is_correct_phone = (bool)preg_march('/^\+\(\d{3}\) \d{2} \d{3} \d{2} \d{2}$/');
```